# Can every set be measurable?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, measure-theory

The Solovay model shows that ZF (plus an inaccessible) is consistent with every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ being measurable.  How far can we go in that direction?  We can always have non-measurable sets by making the $\sigma$-algebra small, so here are two ways of making them big (either seems interesting to me):

1. For every set $X$ there exists a non-trivial measure on the entire power set of $X$.  (Here non-trivial means that points have measure zero.)
2. For every set $X$, the completion of every probability measure on a set $X$ contains the entire power set of $X$.

Are there counterexamples to either of these already in ZF?  If not, what is their consistency strength?  Are either compatible with other axioms set theorists find attractive, such as dependent choice or the axiom of determinacy?

**Edit** James Hanson points out I need to exclude countable sets.

Comment: You cannot have a nontrivial measure on the power set of the first uncountable ordinal. I think you need at most countable choice to prove that.

Comment: Isn't the first uncountable ordinal a measurable cardinal under AD?  Or does measurable cardinal mean something difference in the absence of choice?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: What about subsets of a countable set? You're not going to get a non-trivial countably additive measure there. Similarly if you require a fairly natural homogeneity condition (every subset of non-maximal cardinality has measure zero) then you'd have problems with countable cofinality too.

Comment: Good point.  I need to rule out countable sets as an example.

Comment: Though I have to admit that I don't know if this is sensitive to the definition of "countable" without choice.

Comment: "Solovay model shows that ZF is consistent": I think it shows this assuming the consistency of ZF(C?)+ $\exists$ inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: Right.  I'll fix it.  I assume that any consistency statement here will require even stronger assumptions.

Comment: "consistent with every Lebesgue measurable set being measurable" - you mean "consistent with every subset of the reals being Lebesgue measurable", right?

Comment: Yes.  I apparently can't be trusted to write a simple sentence correctly.

Comment: The restriction of (1) to uncountable sets can hold. Assume every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable, $\omega_1$ is measurable, and every uncountable set admits an injection from either $\omega_1$ or $\mathbb R$. (These conditions hold in $L(\mathbb R)$ assuming $\text{AD}^{L(\mathbb R)}$.) Then there is a nontrivial measure on $P(X)$ for every uncountable set $X$, namely the pushforward of the measure on $P(\omega_1)$ or $P(\mathbb R)$ by an injection into $X$.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg Could you post this as an answer? It seems to be what arsmath is looking for.

Comment: For (2), I assume you're only referring to completions of non-trivial measures (otherwise this fails for $X=2$). In which case, this can hold only vacuously, namely in a model where the closure of the singletons under countable union is the whole universe, e.g. Gitik's model. I suspect for both (1) and (2), what you are really interested in is measures that generalize Lebesgue measure, rather than arbitrary atomless probability measures.

Comment: @RobertFurber I posted this as a comment because I think arsmath may want to modify the nontriviality condition in (1) to rule out the sort of example I have given. If this is not the case, I am happy to post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @arsmath As you see from Gabe's comment, you probably want to strengthen the nontriviality condition in a way that relates the size of $X$ and, say, the completeness of the measure. This requires some care when $X$ is nonwell-orderable.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg I didn't know $AD^{L(\mathbb{R})}$ had such a pretty dichotomy, but you're right that I should tighten my nontriviality condition.  I have trouble thinking about cardinality without choice.  Do you think it's sufficient to rule out that the measure is not a push-forward from a set of strictly smaller cardinality?

Comment: I think it is an interesting condition. Equivalently, you could ask whether it is consistent with ZF that (the powerset of) every set carries a (real-valued) measure that does not concentrate on a smaller set. You then no longer need to exclude countable sets. Note also that one cannot have a measure on a cardinal of cofinality $\omega$ such that every set of strictly smaller cardinality is null. (The AD dichotomy is due to Woodin and is proved in Caicedo-Ketchersid's "A trichotomy theorem in natural models of $\text{AD}^+$" as a consequence of a more general result due to Caicedo-Ketchersid.)